# ipywdiget Jupyter Notebook results are in a console log; how do I get the results in a Jupyter cell instead?

Tags: python

Everything is in the title. I want the results of my ipywdiget to be in a Jupyter cell and not in the console log so if i can have some help please thanks you.

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown, HTML
import requests
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import json

def make_hal_request(query, year, doc_type):
url = f"https://api.archives-ouvertes.fr/search/?q={query}&fq=docType_s:{doc_type}&fq=producedDateY_i:{year}&wt=json"
response = requests.get(url)
try:
    data = response.json()
    return data
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    return None
doc_types = ['ART', 'COMM', 'OUV', 'THESE']
query_widget = widgets.Textarea(value='', placeholder='Saisissez votre requête ici', description='Requête:')
year_widget = widgets.Dropdown(options=['Toutes les années'] + list(range(2010, 2023)), description='Année:')
doc_type_widget = widgets.Dropdown(options=['Tous les types'] + doc_types, description='Type de document:')
display_type_widget = widgets.RadioButtons(options=['Tableau', 'Graphique'], description='Affichage:')
button = widgets.Button(description='Effectuer la requête')
def on_button_click(b):
query = query_widget.value.strip()
year = year_widget.value
doc_type = doc_type_widget.value

if not query:
    display(Markdown('Veuillez saisir une requête valide.'))
    return

if year == 'Toutes les années':
    year = '*'

if doc_type == 'Tous les types':
    doc_type = '*'


data = make_hal_request(query, year, doc_type)

if data is None:
    return

num_results = data['response']['numFound']
display(Markdown(f"Nombre total de documents : {num_results}"))

if display_type_widget.value == 'Tableau':
    if year == '*':
        if doc_type == '*':
            years = list(range(2010, 2023))
            counts = []
            for year in years:
                data = make_hal_request(query, year, doc_type)
                if data is not None:
                    counts.append(data['response']['numFound'])
            
            df = pd.DataFrame({'Année': years, 'Nombre de documents': counts})
            display(df)
        else:
            display(Markdown('Veuillez sélectionner "Toutes les années" pour afficher les résultats sous forme de tableau.'))
    else:
        display(Markdown('Veuillez sélectionner "Toutes les années" pour afficher les résultats sous forme de tableau.'))


elif display_type_widget.value == 'Graphique':
    if year == '*':
        if doc_type == '*':
            years = list(range(2010, 2023))
            counts = []
            for year in years:
                data = make_hal_request(query, year, doc_type)
                if data is not None:
                    counts.append(data['response']['numFound'])
            
            plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
            plt.plot(years, counts, marker='o')
            plt.xlabel('Année')
            plt.ylabel("Nombre de documents")
            plt.title('Nombre de documents publiés par année')
            plt.show()
        else:
            display(Markdown('Veuillez sélectionner "Toutes les années" pour afficher les résultats sous forme de graphique.'))
    else:
        display(Markdown('Veuillez sélectionner "Toutes les années" pour afficher les résultats sous forme de graphique.'))


button.on_click(on_button_click)
display(query_widget, year_widget, doc_type_widget, display_type_widget, button)
```

I need the results to be in the next cell in my Jupyter Notebook if possible. I don't know the website is asking me to explain more my issue.
Thanks you for reading. I hope you have a great day.

Comment: What you describe in the title is exactly what you'll observe if you aren't handling `out` correctly.  I don't se you having a handler for that. You maybe developed this code from outdated resources? Is this a minimal reproducible example meaning it should work on my system if I wanted to run it to try and edit it to work? Right now I see it has syntax error, or at least one after `def on_button_click(b):`. Please copy what you pasted to always test it posted correct & then fix it if you didn't post it right. Meaning always a good idea to start a new notebook and paste in your MRE and run it.

Comment: Essentially your title is describing this situation described here in this post from March 2022 titled ['Jupyterlab output in log rather than cell'](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-output-in-log-rather-than-cell/13419?u=fomightez). See my reply there if you want to start approaching addressing it.